# Problem with Vec using ink

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, vec

I'm trying to make some changes to the Flipper contract, trying to use a vector like the documentation say's it should be imported:

```
#[ink::contract]
pub mod flipper_plus {
    use ink::storage::Mapping;
    use ink::prelude::vec::Vec;
```

and during compilation got this errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::flipper_plus::vec`
 --> /Users/pierina/Documents/rust_projects/flipper-contract/contracts/flipperPlus/src/lib.rs:7:30
  |
7 |     use crate::flipper_plus::vec::Vec;
  |                              ^^^ could not find `vec` in `flipper_plus`

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
  --> /Users/pierina/Documents/rust_projects/flipper-contract/contracts/flipperPlus/src/lib.rs:33:26
   |
33 |                 history: vec![(caller, init_value, Self::env().block_timestamp())], 
   |                          ^^^
```

Here is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "flipper_plus"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.0.0", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[lib]
name = "flipper_plus"
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = [
    # Used for normal contract Wasm blobs.
    "cdylib",
]

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std"
]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

Comment: import in this way @Pierina Ponce `use ink::prelude::{ vec, vec::Vec }`

Answer (score 4):

You only imported `Vec`. So, it could not find `vec!`.

And this error `use crate::flipper_plus::vec::Vec;`. It isn't the same as the code that you provided. `use ink::prelude::vec::Vec;`.

So, please update those imports correctly.

https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/4.1.0/ink_prelude/index.html

```rs
use ink::prelude::{vec, vec::Vec};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need firstly add to your `Cargo.toml` following line:

```
ink_prelude = { version = "4.0.2", default-features = false }
```

and then you can use `vec` like:

```
use ink::prelude::{vec, vec::Vec};
```

Documentation: https://crates.io/crates/ink_prelude